# How do I format my targets to train a Keras CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

My dataset is images of whales. I am trying to train a CNN that can locate 2 points of the whale in the given image. My training features are the image in a numpy array, and the targets are the x and y coordinates of 2 points in the image (2 points on the whale).

What is the best way to make a neural network with Keras that can learn from the dataset I have, so that it will be able to locate those points on new, unlabeled images?

My main problem at the moment is figuring out how to format the target (The 2 points in the image) so that my Keras model can understand/read the data.

The broken code I have is:

```
x_train = np.array([cv2.imread("1small.jpg")])
y_train = np.array([14.1, 13.5, 16.3, 14.1])

x_test = np.array([cv2.imread("0small.jpg")])
y_test = np.array([11.8, 10.8, 17.0, 16.0]) # fake data just to test

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,32,32,3))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1)

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
print prediction
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the points

Comment: They are just the x and y coordinates of the nose and blowhole of the whale in the picture

Answer (score 0):

These networks are fairly good for learning coordinates, so you can leave the data as four coordinates. Then you can define your loss as the sum of distances squared. The first nice thing about that is that it will punish large errors a lot more, and smaller ones less, so it's going to give the network a smooth ride towards perfection. :) The second nice thing is that if you think about it, the squared distance of two points is the sum of the squares of differences of coordinates. So basically you can use the mean square error on the coordinate array as a loss for this network. Nice and easy.

Looking at your network, you should add a few convolution and pooling layers up front, dense layers are not good ones to see the image first. They should be towards the top of the network.

Also, `tanh` activation is so last decade. :) Use `relu`, except for the last layer, which should have no activation.

Also consider transforming your coordinates so that the middle of the image is the origin, and the edges are around -1 and 1. This will normalize the prediction space a bit, might help.

Hope this helps.